# Can't access all adventure works tables on MacOS

Tags: sql-server, mssql-jdbc, adventureworks, dbvisualizer, dbeaver

I have adventure works on local docker container and also on a sql-server. When i try to access adventure works i have only 3 tables. 
On windows it works.
I used DBeaver and DBvisualizer for connection.
[Screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPnfH.png)

SOLVED: in new version of DBeaver it's solved, it's a bug from ms-sql drivers. But in DBvisualizer it still don't work.

Comment: Is this a vanilla AdventureWorks database?
IE just downloaded and no changes at all made?

Comment: Yes, it is a vanilla..

Comment: Looking at the image you are looking at the tables in dbo scheme. AW has multiple schemes (maybe the version on docker only has dbo?).

Comment: @CetinBasoz i looked in all schemes. But actually is not on docker, i was looking on sql-server. When i connect the same server on ms sql management studio it has all tables.

Comment: You mean DBeaver and DBvisualizer don't show them? I don't use them :( Simply check with T_SQL. I access SQL Server tables from a Mac using Go and Go MSSQL libraries with no problem.

Comment: Good spot @CetinBasoz

Comment: @CetinBasoz i just need adventure works for college. How can i use these libraries ?

Comment: OK I add sample call and output as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this docker command:

```
sudo docker exec -it sql1 /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'myStrongP@ssw0rd' -Q "select table_schema,table_name,table_type from AdventureWorks2012.Information_Schema.Tables order by table_type, table_schema, table_name" | tr -s ' '
```

These are the table list I get:

```
table_schema table_name table_type
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
dbo AWBuildVersion BASE TABLE
dbo DatabaseLog BASE TABLE
dbo ErrorLog BASE TABLE
HumanResources Department BASE TABLE
HumanResources Employee BASE TABLE
HumanResources EmployeeDepartmentHistory BASE TABLE
HumanResources EmployeePayHistory BASE TABLE
HumanResources JobCandidate BASE TABLE
HumanResources Shift BASE TABLE
Person Address BASE TABLE
Person AddressType BASE TABLE
Person BusinessEntity BASE TABLE
Person BusinessEntityAddress BASE TABLE
Person BusinessEntityContact BASE TABLE
Person ContactType BASE TABLE
Person CountryRegion BASE TABLE
Person EmailAddress BASE TABLE
Person Password BASE TABLE
Person Person BASE TABLE
Person PersonPhone BASE TABLE
Person PhoneNumberType BASE TABLE
Person StateProvince BASE TABLE
Production BillOfMaterials BASE TABLE
Production Culture BASE TABLE
Production Document BASE TABLE
Production Illustration BASE TABLE
Production Location BASE TABLE
Production Product BASE TABLE
Production ProductCategory BASE TABLE
Production ProductCostHistory BASE TABLE
Production ProductDescription BASE TABLE
Production ProductDocument BASE TABLE
Production ProductInventory BASE TABLE
Production ProductListPriceHistory BASE TABLE
Production ProductModel BASE TABLE
Production ProductModelIllustration BASE TABLE
Production ProductModelProductDescriptionCulture BASE TABLE
Production ProductPhoto BASE TABLE
Production ProductProductPhoto BASE TABLE
Production ProductReview BASE TABLE
Production ProductSubcategory BASE TABLE
Production ScrapReason BASE TABLE
Production TransactionHistory BASE TABLE
Production TransactionHistoryArchive BASE TABLE
Production UnitMeasure BASE TABLE
Production WorkOrder BASE TABLE
Production WorkOrderRouting BASE TABLE
Purchasing ProductVendor BASE TABLE
Purchasing PurchaseOrderDetail BASE TABLE
Purchasing PurchaseOrderHeader BASE TABLE
Purchasing ShipMethod BASE TABLE
Purchasing Vendor BASE TABLE
Sales CountryRegionCurrency BASE TABLE
Sales CreditCard BASE TABLE
Sales Currency BASE TABLE
Sales CurrencyRate BASE TABLE
Sales Customer BASE TABLE
Sales PersonCreditCard BASE TABLE
Sales SalesOrderDetail BASE TABLE
Sales SalesOrderHeader BASE TABLE
Sales SalesOrderHeaderSalesReason BASE TABLE
Sales SalesPerson BASE TABLE
Sales SalesPersonQuotaHistory BASE TABLE
Sales SalesReason BASE TABLE
Sales SalesTaxRate BASE TABLE
Sales SalesTerritory BASE TABLE
Sales SalesTerritoryHistory BASE TABLE
Sales ShoppingCartItem BASE TABLE
Sales SpecialOffer BASE TABLE
Sales SpecialOfferProduct BASE TABLE
Sales Store BASE TABLE
HumanResources vEmployee VIEW 
HumanResources vEmployeeDepartment VIEW 
HumanResources vEmployeeDepartmentHistory VIEW 
HumanResources vJobCandidate VIEW 
HumanResources vJobCandidateEducation VIEW 
HumanResources vJobCandidateEmployment VIEW 
Person vAdditionalContactInfo VIEW 
Person vStateProvinceCountryRegion VIEW 
Production vProductAndDescription VIEW 
Production vProductModelCatalogDescription VIEW 
Production vProductModelInstructions VIEW 
Purchasing vVendorWithAddresses VIEW 
Purchasing vVendorWithContacts VIEW 
Sales vIndividualCustomer VIEW 
Sales vPersonDemographics VIEW 
Sales vSalesPerson VIEW 
Sales vSalesPersonSalesByFiscalYears VIEW 
Sales vStoreWithAddresses VIEW 
Sales vStoreWithContacts VIEW 
Sales vStoreWithDemographics VIEW
```

All the tables are there in docker container, under their designated schemas.

" i just need adventure works for college. How can i use these libraries" 
I don't understand what you mean by this. Above docker command listing the tables is one way of using it. You could also run it from within the docker container using sqlcmd shell. Maybe you should explain better what you are trying to do. 
FWIW on a Mac or Linux I would simply use something like postgreSQL.

Comment: We are studying "select", and we don't need to do any changes on adventure works db. I have to do my homework, but at home i don't have any windows pc to study select instructions with ms sql management studio. And i need adventure works on mac os. I tried AdventureWorksDW, this one is working, i created my own db and also it works. But i need to work with adventure works 2012 / 2014.

Comment: OK simply use that and you can run commands like: Select * from HumanResources.Employee. It would be easier to run from within docker image sqlcmd shell.

Comment: Maybe in your tool, there is a selection to show other schemas too (ie: in Jetbrains datagrip, using mysql jdbc by default shows only dbo schema).

Comment: I used in connection in DBeaver, option "Show all schemas" and i have few new schemas, but they are also empty https://ibb.co/nsgeTH

Comment: I am sorry I don't generally use tools and simply write my SQL commands.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed on MacOS using the jTDS driver will not list all the schemas in a SQL Server Database, so I imagine that issue could extend to tables as well. Switch to the MS JDBC driver and see if that fixes things.